# Keycloak cluster fails on Amazon ECS (org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache)

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, amazon-ecs, jgroups

I am trying to deploy a cluster of 2 [Keycloak docker images](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/server/README.md) (6.0.1) on Amazon ECS (Fargate) using the built-in [ECS Service Discovery mecanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) (using DNS_PING).

Environment:

```
JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL=dns.DNS_PING
JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES=dns_query=my.services.internal,dns_record_type=A
JGROUPS_TRANSPORT_STACK=tcp <---(also tried udp)
```

The instances IP are correctly resolved from Route53 private namespace and they discover each other without any problem (x.x.x.138 is started first, then x.x.x.76).

Second instance:

```
[org.jgroups.protocols.dns.DNS_PING] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ip-x.x.x.76: entries collected from DNS (in 3 ms): [x.x.x.76:0, x.x.x.138:0]
[org.jgroups.protocols.dns.DNS_PING] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ip-x.x.x.76: sending discovery requests to hosts [x.x.x.76:0, x.x.x.138:0] on ports [55200 .. 55200]
[org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ip-x.x.x.76: sending JOIN(ip-x-x-x-76) to ip-x-x-x-138
```

And on the first instance:

```
[org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,ip-x-x-x-138) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [ip-x-x-x-138|1] (2) [ip-x-x-x-138, ip-172-x-x-x-76]
[org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (thread-8,ejb,ip-x-x-x-138) Joined: [ip-x-x-x-76], Left: []
[org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-8,ejb,ip-x-x-x-138) ISPN100000: Node ip-x-x-x-76 joined the cluster
[org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK] (FD_SOCK pinger-12,ejb,ip-x-x-x-76) ip-x-x-x-76: pingable_mbrs=[ip-x-x-x-138, ip-x-x-x-76], ping_dest=ip-x-x-x-138
```

So it seems we have a working cluster. Unfortunately, the second instance ends up failing with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on ip-x-x-x-76
```

Before this occurs, I am seeing a bunch of failure discovery task suspecting/unsuspecting the opposite instance:

```
[org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL] (Timer runner-1,null,null) haven't received a heartbeat from ip-x-x-x-76 for 60016 ms, adding it to suspect list
[org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL] (Timer runner-1,null,null) ip-x-x-x-138: suspecting [ip-x-x-x-76]
[org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL] (thread-9,ejb,ip-x-x-x-138) Unsuspecting ip-x-x-x-76
[org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK] (thread-9,ejb,ip-x-x-x-138) ip-x-x-x-138: broadcasting unsuspect(ip-x-x-x-76)
```

On the Infinispan side (cache), everything seems to occur correctly but I am not sure. Every cache is "rebalanced" and each "rebalance" seems to end up with, for example:

```
[org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] (transport-thread--p24-t2) Finished receiving of segments for cache offlineSessions for topology 2.
```

It feels like its a connectivity issue, but all the ports are wide open between these 2 instances, both for TCP and UDP.

Any idea ? Anyone successfull at configuring this on ECS (fargate) ?

**UPDATE 1**
The second instance was initially shutting down not because of the "Initial state transfer timed out .." error but because the health check was taking longer than the configured grace period. Nonetheless, with 2 healthy instances, I receive "404 - Not Found" once every 2 queries, telling me that there is indeed a cache problem.

Comment: I have no experience with ECS but cloud providers often block UDP. I suggest running with TCP stack only.

Comment: even if I set JGROUPS_TRANSPORT_STACK=tcp, discovery uses port 55200 which I think is udp, but I am not sure. I dont see any other way to force TCP in the docs.

Comment: Just found https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10198 which introduces the JGROUPS_TRANSPORT_STACK variable. Will be available in Keycloak 7.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current keycloak docker image (6.0.1), the default stack is UDP. According to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10198), version 7.0.0 will default to TCP and will also introduce a variable to toggle the stack (JGROUPS_TRANSPORT_STACK).

Using the UDP stack in Amazon ECS will "partially" work, meaning the discovery will work, the cluster will form, but the Infinispan cache won't be able to sync between instances, which will produce erratic errors. There is probably a way to make it work "as-is", but I dont see anything blocked between the instances when checking the VPC Flow logs.

A workaround is to switch to TCP by modifying the JGroups stack directly in the image in file /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:6.0">                                                                                                                                                                             
     <channels default="ee">                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         <channel name="ee" stack="tcp" cluster="ejb"/>   <-- set stack to tcp                                                                                                                                                                    
     </channels>
```

Then commit the new image:

```
docker commit -m="TCP cluster stack" CONTAINER_ID jboss/keycloak:6.0.1-tcp-cluster
```

Tag/Push the image to Amazon ECR and make sure the port 7600 is accepted in your security group between your Amazon ECS tasks.